# Adding model with user input and hard coded values

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Okay so I am using the MVC framework. I have a view for adding a model. At the moment I am using the default "Create" controller.

I want to be able to create a model with my own variables pre-set. For example the model.UserId I want to set to the users Id. I want some values to be inputed by the user and I want some to be already set. Is there a way I could do something like this

(pseudo code)

```
model.matchId = 123
model.prediction type = "user input"
add model
```

here is my current code below

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Predictions</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MatchId, "Match")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("MatchId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MatchId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, "User")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("UserId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Type)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Type)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Prediction)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Prediction)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Prediction)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, you would set the values on the model before returning it to the View.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            var model = new MyModel();
            model.SomeId = 123;
            model.SomeOtherProperty = "Hello World";
            return View(model);
        } 
 }
```